# A Way To Improve Sorting Algorithms?

Tags: sorting

For sorting algorithms, why can't you just cut the array in half, and just use selection sort or insertion sort on both, and put them back together, to significantly improve the speed?

Comment: have you heard of quick sort? or merge sort? A lot of data is different and the type of sort could be different based on that.

Comment: it depends on which algorithm you wanted to use because each algorithm have their own reason to use so first match your requirement with different algorithms then you can decide which one you wanted to use.

Comment: First you have to show that it *would* significantly improve the speed, and secondly you would have to mention which sorting algorithms you're talking about, as some of them already do this, or better. You're radically underestimating about 65 years of research here.

Answer (score 1):

You're saying that your algorithm is faster than existing sorts, for example, selection sort and insertion sort. But then, once you've split your array in half, you'd be better using your algorithm rather than selection/insertion sort to sort the halves (perhaps unless the halves are small).

This is exactly merge-sort.

Answer (score 0):

You are right. This approach is followed in some sorting algorithms. For example in Merge sort which divides the array into two halves and if these two halves are small, you can apply insertion sort directly on them but if they are large then it would not be feasible as you better divide the halves too (please see the details of Merge sort) . Insertion sort/Selection sort/Bubble sort perform better when array is small or generally on nearly sorted data. If you are tackling long data then choose Merge sort/Quick sort/Redix sort.